# Hibernate Annotations - How do I exclude a bean´s field from mapping?

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I´ve got a bean containing some fields, and two of them are not intended to be mapped by hibernate (errorStatus and operationResultMessage). How do I tell Hibernate (via annotations) that I don´t want to map those fields?

*The mapped table in the beans does not have the fields: errorStatus and operationResultMessage

Thanks in advance.

Code right bellow:

** Gettters and Setters ommited!

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class AccountBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String userName;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

private Boolean errorStatus;

private String operationResultMessage;
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the [`@Transient`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html) annotation.

---

```
/* snip... */

@Transient
private Boolean errorStatus;

@Transient
private String operationResultMessage;
```

Obviously, if you're annotating the getters/setters rather than the fields, that's where the `@Transient` annotation would go.

Comment: Thanks for your tip Matt, it was quiet usefull!