# Creating an instance of Entity in Spring without any Spring interaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my project based on `spring-data-rest` I have some classes annotated with the `@Entity` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyTable extends BaseTableEntity {
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Now I am not quite sure as to how Spring handles creation of new instances of classes annotated with that annotation. I needed to create an object of such an `Entity` class making sure that no database operations takes place.

To make it clear, say I do `MyTable table = new MyTable()` in a POJO class. Can I be sure that Spring with the help of Hibernate/JPA won't create records in my database. What if I do the same in a `@Component` class instead of a POJO.

Comment: remove @Table and make sure you have not allowed creation of table in properties file

Comment: Short answer: yes you can be sure.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan Could you elaborate a bit? I have the `@Table` annotation since I want to manage automatic table creation for these entities. Its just that sometimes I want to create a POJO from the same annotated class without bothering about the database.

Comment: @Andronicus So, I can be sure that unless I do `MyTableRepository.save(table)`, the `table` object won't be monitored by Spring for updates and stuff.

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay yes, see my answer;)

Comment: so you want to use same class ? some time for data manipulation in db  and some time as a pojo?

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan exactly.

Comment: @SayakMukhopadhyay You can simple annotate the entity with Transient annotation and the class will be excluded from mapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Annotations - How do I exclude a bean´s field from mapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386487/hibernate-annotations-how-do-i-exclude-a-bean%c2%b4s-field-from-mapping)

Comment: @ChristosK. I don't think this is a duplicate. The linked question talks about letting out some fields withing a class marked as an `@Entity` whereas my question talks about Spring handling the object itself.

Comment: You don't specify what exactly are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to annotate a class as an Entity and Table but keep Hibernate from mapping that class to your database? Do you want to just prevent accidental persistance of entries? Also as the Andronicus states in his answer, just by declaring your class as Entity/Table won't write anything to your database, to have an "accident" like that you would need to be in a Transactional class i.e. in a class annotated as repository and on top of that use merge,persist,save etc..

Comment: My very last line of the question tries to clarify my question in the simplest way possible. I am looking for a basically yes/no answer with a short explanation as to the reason, which Andronicus was able to provide extremely quickly and efficiently and bears no resemblance as to the question linked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new entity with `new` keyword does not make any insert into db. The entity is in detached state. You would have to pass this entity to `reporitory.save` or `entityManager.persist` or `entityManager.merge`... But as long `persist` is not invoked (directly or indirectly), it's a regular pojo without a representation in database.

Comment: And what in case of load data?

Comment: What do you mean? If you load something from database, you need to call `entityManager.detach(entity);`